# Scheduled information upload to Magento - XML best option?

Tags: xml, magento, e-commerce

I'm setting up a new Magento based ecom store. Other than the standard CSV import is there a way of setting up a timed XML or similar to update product levels, details etc to and from a local source? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  You can use [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) to do quick, efficient product imports and updates.

With Magmi, you can upload a CSV containing your products, configure Magmi to use it.

Then for a schedule, you can setup a cronjob to run Magmi.  You can have your cronjob run the following command:

```
php magmi.cli.php [-profile=<yourprofilename>] [-mode=[update|create|xcreate]]
```

More documentation on using the Magmi CLI interface can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_command_line